# Want to build a table like that

Tags: tables, itemize

I want to make a table like this, but I'm still having some problems:

1. can't put the text in center of the box
2. can't `\flushleft` the table title
3. can't `itemize` in the table

[image]

Help me!

Here is my LATEX

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.75cm,right=2.25cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry} % Page margins

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored

\usepackage{lipsum} % Inserts dummy text

\usepackage{tikz} % Required for drawing custom shapes

\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation

\usepackage{enumitem} % Customize lists
\setlist{nolistsep} % Reduce spacing between bullet points and numbered lists

\usepackage{booktabs} % Required for nicer horizontal rules in tables

\usepackage{xcolor} % Required for specifying colors by name

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

%%% FOR TABLE
\newcommand{\signaldes}[3]
{#1 & #2 & #3 \\ \hline}

\newcommand{\groupsignal}[1]
{
    %\begin{centering}
    %#1 \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\bfseries{#1}} \\ \hline
    %\end{centering}
}   

\newenvironment{signaltable}[1]
    {%\ttabbox[\FBwidth]{}{%
        %\captionsetup{justification=raggedleft,singlelinecheck=off}
        \captionof{table}{Signal Description Table #1} \label{tab:title}
    \begin{tabular}%{>{\bfseries}c c c}%
        {|l | l | p{8cm} |} %>{\bfseries}: in đậm 
        \specialrule{2pt}{1pt}{1pt}
        \bfseries{Signal} & \bfseries{Source} & \bfseries{Description} \\
        \specialrule{2pt}{1pt}{1pt} 
        %\bfseries{#1} & #2 & #3. \\
        %\hline
    %}
    }
    {   
    \end{tabular}}

\section*{SECTION1}
\lipsum[1]

\section*{SECTION2}
\begin{signaltable}{Bus AXI}
  \signaldes{s\_axi\_lite\_aclk}{SLAVER}{AXI DMA AXI4-Lite Clock. Must be less than or equal to axi\_sg\_aclk for asynchronous mode.(C\_PRMRY\_IS\_ACLK\_ASYNC=1).}
  \signaldes{m\_axi\_sg\_aclk}{MASTER}{AXI DMA Scatter Gather Clock. Scatter Gather clock must be less than or equal to the slowest of m\_axi\_mm2s\_aclk or m\_axi\_s2mm\_aclk for asynchronous mode.(C\_PRMRY\_IS\_ACLK\_ASYNC=1).}
  \signaldes{m\_axi\_mm2s\_aclk}{MASTER}{AXI DMA MM2S Primary Clock}
  \signaldes{m\_axi\_s2mm\_aclk}{MASTER}{AXI DMA S2MM Primary Clock}
  \groupsignal{AXI4 Lite Interface Signals}
  \signaldes{s\_axi\_lite\_awvalid}{SLAVER}{AXI4-Lite Write Address Channel Write Address Valid.
    \textbullet\ 1 = Write address is valid.\\
    \textbullet\ 0 = Write address is not valid.}
  \signaldes{s\_axi\_lite\_awready}{SLAVER}{AXI4-Lite Write Address Channel Write Address Ready. Indicates DMA ready to accept the write address.\\
    \tabitem 1 = Ready to accept address.\\
    \tabitem 0 = Not ready to accept address.}
\end{signaltable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of yelling "HELP ME" perhaps you could post some code that shows what you've tried and what is causing you problems. A complete, compilable *minimal* document (no extra packages, code etc.) Also, have you searched the site for table formatting questions? There are lots of examples of how to do this already on the site.

Comment: Tks for your recomment. I had posted my code above, you can use to try to fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `vertical` centering can be obtained using the `m` columntype which has the width of the column as an argument.

I used a `tabularx` table to provide the rest of the available width for the `Description` column, using `X` columntype.

Both `p` and `X` allow wrapping of longer lines as well as enumeration or itemize environments.

I omitted the vertical lines on purpose as they do not improve readability.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.75cm,right=2.25cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\newlength{\smallcolumnwidth}
\setlength{\smallcolumnwidth}{1.2cm}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{4}{p{\smallcolumnwidth}}X}
\toprule[1.5pt]
\multicolumn{1}{m{\smallcolumnwidth}}{\textbf{Signal Name}} & \multicolumn{1}{m{\smallcolumnwidth}}{\textbf{Interface}} & \multicolumn{1}{m{\smallcolumnwidth}}{\textbf{Signal Type}} & \multicolumn{1}{m{\smallcolumnwidth}}{\textbf{Init Status}} &  \textbf{Description} \tabularnewline
\midrule[1pt]
foo & foo & foo & foo & A longer longer longer text that is most likely wrapped around \tabularnewline

\midrule
foo & foo & foo & foo & Another longer text that is most likely wrapped around again \tabularnewline
\midrule
foo & foo & foo & foo & A longer text that is not wrapped around \tabularnewline
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{m{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}{\centering \textbf{AXI4-Lite Interface Signals}} \tabularnewline
\midrule
  foo & foo & foo & foo & foo 
  \begin{itemize}
  \item foo
  \item another foo
  \end{itemize} \tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I won't fill in the text for the O.P. of course ;-)

Comment: How about editing my code? :D

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  I would also recommend to start and end the definition of columns with `@{}` to get rid of the extra space at the start of the leftmost and end of the rightmost column in the table.

Answer (score 7):

> can't put the text in center of the box

I suggest the `tabulary` package (or `tabularx` suggested by Christian, depending of type of columns of the table you may want one or another)

> can't \flushleft the table title

```
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=off}
```

> can't itemize in the table

Use a `\parbox`. It is essentially the same that use a `p` column, but you can use also it in another column types.

A reduced MWE:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{booktabs} % Required for nicer horizontal rules in tables
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Signal Description Table Bus AXI}  
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{llccLL}
\toprule
s\_axi\_lite\_aclk &
SLAVER & 
I & & AXI DMA AXI4-Lite Clock. Must be less than or equal to axi\_sg\_aclk for asynchronous mode. (C\_PRMRY\_IS\_ACLK\_ASYNC=1) \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\bfseries AXI4 Lite Interface Signals}\\
\midrule
 s\_axi\_lite\_awvalid & 
 SLAVER & 
 O & 0 & 
 AXI4-Lite Write Address Channel Write Address Valid. 
%\parbox{\linewidth}{
\begin{itemize}
\item 1 = Write address is valid.
\item 0 = Write address is not valid.   
\end{itemize}
%}
\tabularnewline\bottomrule 
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, I saw that I forgot the caption ;-)